# Getting 1004 when trying to select a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting

> 1004 error

while running the below macro, in line
`Worksheets("Testable").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select`

```
Sub colour()
    Dim cell As Range

    Worksheets("Testable").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select
    For Each cell In Selection

        cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the goal? Do yu just want to make column A blue from row `2` to the bottom of the data? You don't need a loop to do that.

Comment: Actually no, it looks like you're trying to to make all of every row blue, except for Row 1.  You need to carify your goal please.  Answers from my or anyone else are only guessing what you need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `Select` or `Activate` the worksheet.  Then `Select` the range.

Here is a working example:

```
Sub colour()
    Dim cell As Range
    Worksheets("Testable").Activate
    Worksheets("Testable").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#2:**
To avoid both looping and selection, use something like:

```
Sub colourAlternative()
    Dim cell As Range
    With Worksheets("Testable")
        Set cell = Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown)).EntireRow
    End With
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
End Sub
```

There were three things at issue here:

1. why `Select` failed
2. avoiding `Select`
3. avoiding the loop

Comment: well, better avoid select at all.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  I completely agree with you.

Comment: Hi, Now i have changed the code as below. But still receiving error as: "Unable to get the Interior Property of the range class"

Sub colourTestable()
    Dim cell As Range
    Worksheets("Testable").Select
    Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Select
    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
    Next cell
End Sub

Comment: I need to use the select as i need to colour code the rows till which the data exists.

Comment: I don't understand how/why you guys pick-and-choose which poorly written, incomplete questions you're going to answer and which you're going to flag.

Comment: @Maitreya no, you can also do this without select. There is no need to select something in Excel if you just want to change the color this works also without using select.

Comment: @Maitreya Please don't add code in comments, you can [edit] your question if you need to add more information.  Also it would be a good idea to check out "[ask]" as well as "[mcve]".

Comment: @Maitreya  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gary'sStudent foor your effort and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below you will find a simple and foolproof (based on the details in the original question) way to accomplish your task:

```
With Worksheets("Testable")
    .Range(.Range("A2"),.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).EntireRow.InteriorColorIndex = 33
End With
```

The reason you get an error in the line

```
Worksheets("Testable").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select
```

is because the two `Range("A2")` parts of the statement are unqualified and Excel does not know what to do with them (especially if the `Testable` sheet is not the active sheet). By qualifying them in the way I did above, you avoid selecting the object and work directly with it, thus optimizing the code execution.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott for the explanation. I think it was just because the worksheet was not active while selecting the range. Your code worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: @Maitreya Yes. But the point is that in this case (and in most cases) it's *not necessary* for the sheet to be selected / active and using that style of coding can slow down your code. There are *certain* cases where it is necessary to select / activate a sheet, but they are few.